# creating div and image overlay over a video that hides on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/2fAxv/1/
But the second `div` `#hide`should be on the top left of the screen with some margin. Can't figure that out. Also, once the image is clicked on the youtube video shrinks to a default size.Is there a way to fix it's size in the same code without using `<iframe>`

html

```
<div class="vid">
    <img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Z7JgY9zezj4/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z7JgY9zezj4?autoplay=1" />
    <div id="hide1">
        <h3>johnny Depp<br><span>Acting Technique</span></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.vid {
width: 350px;
height: 298px;
float: left;
margin: 20px 25px 70px 70px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 0px -50px;
background-repeat: none;
}
.vid div {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 298px;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32); 
 }
 .vid div h3 {
 position: absolute;
 color: black;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 margin-left: 30px;
 max-width: 450px;
 }
 .vid div h3 span {
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 width: 300px;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 19px;
 }
```

function

```
$('#hide').click(function() {
    video = '<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '"></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
    $('#hide1').hide();
});
```

Comment: "*the second `div` `#hide` should be on the top left of the screen with some margin.*" - whereabouts, exactly? With what margin? "*Top left*" of the *screen*, or *top left of the `.vid` element*?

Comment: `video = '<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '" width="'+$(this).width()+'" height="'+$(this).height()+'"></iframe>';` will solve the resizing problem

Comment: @DavidThomas something like this http://prntscr.com/7cjf57

Comment: @Markai tried doing that. It is not working for me. Could you please edit in the fiddle if it is working for you.Thanks.

Comment: @turtle oh, without iframe, sorry, didn't recognize that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the sizing problem, I'd suggest:

```
$('img').click(function () {
    // creating an <iframe> element:
    var video = $('<iframe />', {

        // setting its properties,
        // this.dataset.video returns the
        // value of the 'data-video' attribute:
        'src': this.dataset.video,

            // retrieves the height/width:
            'height': this.clientHeight,
            'width': this.clientWidth
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2fAxv/641/).

The positioning can be solved, depending on where you want the element to be positioned, by simply using `position: absolute` on the element to position (the `#hide1` element, with `position: relative` on the parent `.vid` element):

```
.vid {
    /* other (unchanged) styles omitted for brevity */
    position: relative;
}
.vid div {
    /* other (unchanged) styles removed for brevity */
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}
/* some minor changes follow,
   just for tidying up/aesthetics;
   but irrelevant to the 'positioning'
   aspect */
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2fAxv/642/).

References:

- CSS:

  - `position`.
- JavaScript:

  - [`Element.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth).
  - [`Element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Comment: Thank you so much.Been at it for hours. Just one question, is there a way to get rid of the black space on top and bottom of the image?

Comment: Yes; but that question (and many similar questions) are answered already elsewhere on the site; searching (admittedly, via Google or any other search engine of your choice, rather than SO's search) should result in useful information.